# Print scales down when silent is set to true in Electron

Tags: electron

I want to print a electron window. But when I set `silent: true` but prints fine with ``silent: false`. I have tried setting pageSize and scalingFactor but that does not work.

Electron verison: 28.1.0

**electron-main.js**

```js
function createPrintWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    title: 'Bill Print',
    show: false,
  });

  win.loadFile(path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'test.html')))
  win.webContents.on('dom-ready', () => {
    win.webContents.print({ silent: false, deviceName: 'Microsoft Print to PDF' }, (data, error) => {
      if (error) throw error;
    });
  });
}
```

**Output with `silent: false`**

[image: Output with silent: false]

**Output with `silent: true`**

[image: Output with silent: true]

Answer (score 2):

This has been a known long term issue in version 25+ since it was working in now EOL version 24.
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/39179

There have been several updates that attempt to resolve so always try the latest update. There is one suggested workaround for SOME users (600dpi) !.

Until the issue is fully resolved, you may wish to stick with your last known working version.